# OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Am trying to initiate a request to an API (https://theteller.net/documentation#theTeller_Standard) but i keep getting this error. The idea is that will take details of the user and pass it to my views.py to send a request to to make payment and be redirected back to my website.
This is the error

```
ProxyError at /vote/test/robert-yenji/

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='test.theteller.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /checkout/initiate (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
```

this is my code

````
views.py

 def nomination_payView(request, slug):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            model = get_object_or_404(Nomination, slug=slug)
            template_name = 'Payment.html'
            context = {
                'nomination': model
            }
            return render(request, 'Payment.html', context)
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            amount = (str(int(request.POST['amount']) * 0.5) + '0').replace('.', '')
            zeros = '0' * (12 - len(amount))
            amount = zeros + amount
            email = request.POST['email']
            desc = request.POST['desc']

            url = 'https://test.theteller.net/checkout/initiate'
            transaction_id = random.randint(100000000000, 999999999999)
            data = {
                "merchant_id": "TTM-00000740",
                "transaction_id": transaction_id,
                "amount": amount,
                "redirect_url": f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/process-payment/{slug}/{amount}",
                "apiuser": "halotech5d525bfd6ead3",
                "API_Key": "ZDQ2OGEyZDNjN2YzMDY5ZDVkY2MyM2U5YTRiMGI0N2Q=",
                "email": email,  # you would need to change this to the actual users email
                "desc": desc,  # this as well...

            }
            encoded = base64.b64encode(
                b'halotech5d525bfd6ead3:ZDQ2OGEyZDNjN2YzMDY5ZDVkY2MyM2U5YTRiMGI0N2Q=')  # change this as well
            headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded.decode("utf-8")}',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
            }
            res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers).json()
            print(res['checkout_url'])
            return redirect(res["checkout_url"])```


[This is the error i get ][1]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA3xZ.png
````

Comment: It is saying error 403 which is access forbidden. The website knows you are trying to access it and is intentionally blocking you

Comment: That mean i should contact API owners for assistance?

Comment: Doubt they will help as they have intentionally blocked the public from scraping their code. If they didn't mind people accessing their website, you wouldn't have had error 403 in the first place

Comment: Actually it works on my locally but gives me the error when i moved the project to hosting on  pythonanywhere.com

Answer (score 2):

It's because pythonanywhere.com allows only a specific whitelist of sites to be accessed. Check the following link for more information:
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/
You will have to upgrade your account to get unrestricted access.